# Is setting singleton to nil a good policy or it should never be set to nil? [iOS, Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

I know we should completely avoid `singleton`, as its difficult to test them in `unit testing`.
Let assume someone has written a code for `singleton` and i have been assigned task to write `unit tests` for it.

Is setting `singleton` to `nil` a good policy or it should never be set to nil?

If setting to them is `nil` policy then,
should i make it an `optional` or should i crate a `private setter` and `public getter`, then later on write `reset()` function to make `singleton` `nil` ?

Why I want to set to `nil`  to perform `unit test` on `singleton class`.

ok, i would like to extend this question. assuminng that its not good practise to set singleton nil. Another query in mind is, suppose someone has already written code for singleton class.

now they have assigned task to you to test that singleton class. (not the other class which uses them).

how to work on that ? as for SUT, we mostly alloc SUT in setup() method and set to nil in teardown() method.
but since it is singleton , we can not set to nil, and also in setup() me can't alloc it, we can refer to same object again and again.

Comment: A singleton should never be `nil` - There should always be one instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

**First thing Singleton class should never be nil. As it's name says we are allocating memory for singleton class only once.**
You Can't 'deinit' singleton class if you want to test you can do it like creating methods.
e.g if your singleton class is for like NotificationManager then create two methods subscribeForNotification() & unsubscribeForNotification() You can init or deinit object available in singleton class but not deinit singleton class.